# How to use Different font for LabelField like Arial,TimesNewRoman in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, fonts, font-size, font-face, blackberry-widgets

Hi friends I am using LabelFields to display text message in a screen i want different fonts each LabelField but when i am using api fonts of blackberry using

FontFamily fontFamily[] = FontFamily.getFontFamilies();
 Font font2 = fontFamily[0].getFont(FontFamily.SFF4_FONT,18);

is showing bold style how to use different font styles plz help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 FontFamily alphaSerifFamily = FontFamily.forName("BBAlpha Serif"); 
 Font appFont = alphaSerifFamily.getFont(Font.PLAIN,7,Ui.UNITS_pt);

 LabelField lb = new LabelField("Test");
 lb.setFont(appFont);
```